# How can I do bidirectional communication in Dart with a StreamChannel?

Tags: stream, dart

Is there a way with Dart Streams to do something like 
`await stream.first` multiple times in a row, to use a stream a bit like a stack/queue?

As I understand it, you could do that by using asBroadcastStream on an existing Single-substription stream, but I feel like this isn't ideal.

Maybe there's a kind of buffer primitive with some Rx package or something like that?

My use case is the following:

I have a `StreamChannel` (`IOWebSocketChannel`) and I want to send/receive messages in a specific order.

ie:

```
Send Message0
Receive Message1
Send Message2
Receive Message3
```

and I know for sure that `Message1` will only arrive after the server has received `Message0`
(and so on for `Message2` and `Message3`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dart has both an advantage (and in my opinion, disadvantage) of having a single abstraction for both push-based events *and* pull-based resource reading. This has led to a bunch of other confusion such as ["Do I have to cancel stream subscriptions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879438/dart-do-i-have-to-cancel-stream-subscriptions-and-close-streamsinks/49884064#49884064).

In a push-based model, say:

```
abstract class Element {
  Stream<MouseEvent> get onClick;
}
```

You are *notified* by the class when a *click* occurs. There could anywhere between 0 and literally infinite click events, and it's not typical to want to buffer or process them in the same way you would for reading a resource (especially given that Dart is single-threaded). *Another note*: It's totally valid to have *any* number of subscribers to this stream (multiple classes might be interested in knowing when a click happens).

On the other hand, there is a pull-based model, for say, reading a file:

```
abstract class File {
  Stream<String> readLines();
}
```

In *this* case, you might want to process line-by-line, perhaps even stopping once you hit a certain string, and you *definitely* want to be notified by EOF (usually by a "done" event, or the stream closing, in idiomatic Dart). *Another note*: It's *not* valid to have more than 1 subscriber - that would get tricky real fast.

For your particular question, it seems you want to:

- Send your own event
- Receive the *next* event on-demand
- Process the event, the send your own event
- etc...

OK, let's get to the specifics of your question:

---

> As I understand it, you could do that by using asBroadcastStream on an existing Single-substription stream, but I feel like this isn't ideal.

Very non-ideal. Single-subscription streams (I call these "resource streams" in my head, like the `readLines` call above) *automatically* buffer events and wait for a subscriber. It would be really bad to *not* receive a line(s) of text because the subscription happened *after* the file was read.

On the other hand, a broadcast stream does *not* buffer events. So you could find yourself *losing* events sent if you went with your approach depending on timing issues, etc.

There are a couple options here. None are perfect, but they might help:

- The [`package:stream_transform`](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/stream_transform) package has a set of commonly-needed transformations for a `Stream`, including a few that are RX-inspired.
- The [`package:async`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/async/2.0.6/) package has other utilities for working with asynchronous code. Specifically here you might find the [`StreamQueue`](https://www.dartdocs.org/documentation/async/latest/async/StreamQueue-class.html) does exactly what you want:

  ```
  Future<void> processEvents(Stream<String> inputStream) async {
    var queue = new StreamQueue(inputStream);
    while (await queue.hasNext) {
      var next = await queue.next;
      // Insert processing here.
    }
  }
  ```

I sort of find myself wishing that `StreamQueue` was *in* `dart:async`, and there wasn't a shared interface between `Stream`s used for resources and streams used for events, but this is a decent approach today.

Cheers!

Comment: Great answer, sir! Coming from other places to Dart, this answer and the linked thread was really helpful.