# Should I cancel StreamSubscription after closing Stream?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, stream

After closing streamSink, do I still need to cancel listeners?

Found this answer: [Dart: Do I have to cancel Stream subscriptions and close StreamSinks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49879438/dart-do-i-have-to-cancel-stream-subscriptions-and-close-streamsinks/49884064#49884064)

> In general, when you are done listening to that Stream, for any reason, you should close the subscription

**So if I don't cancel subscription - they would be kept open forever? Garbage collector would not deal with them?**

```
  StreamController<int> controller = StreamController<int>();
  Stream stream = controller.stream;
  StreamSubscription subscription = stream.listen((value) {
    print('Value from controller: $value');
  })
    ..onDone(() => print('done'));
  // prints : Value from controller: 1
  controller.add(1);
  // prints : done
  controller.close();
  // still listening to closed stream
  // no error - cancels successfully
  Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () => subscription.cancel());
```

Comment: There is no need to do that.

Comment: @Antoniossss If you can you provide a doc link or an explanation as to why it is not needed? If would a great help and resource for the community.

Comment: I can't provide you any reference, but if you're handling everything in your `StreamController`, like closing it when done sending the events, you won't need to do the additional step of cancelling the `StreamSubscription`. But if you're not in full control of the stream, it's better to cancel the `StreamSubscription`.

Comment: @iDecode I am also assuming this, but could not find any info regarding it...

Answer (score 5):

Ive tested it today and it is not required to `cancel()` a `StreamSubscription` when the controller is closed because controller will emit `done` when closed and remove all listeners.

Example:

```dart
import "dart:async";

void main() {
  
  final _controller = StreamController();
  
  final _listener = _controller.stream.listen((e) => print("Listener $e"), onDone: () => print("onDone"));
  
  _controller.add(1);
  _controller.add(2);
  _controller.add(3);
  
  _controller.close().then((_) {
    print("hasListener ${_controller.hasListener}");
  });
  
  
}
```

Output:

```
Listener 1
Listener 2
Listener 3
onDone
hasListener false
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-async/Stream-class.html):

> When the "done" event is fired, subscribers are unsubscribed before receiving the event. After the event has been sent, the stream has no subscribers. Adding new subscribers to a broadcast stream after this point is allowed, but they will just receive a new "done" event as soon as possible.

Comment: Do I still need to cancel subscriptions after done event? As far as I understand they are not closed...

Answer (score 1):

So closing steam means you will not be able to add further events,

And if you do this:

```
controller.close();
controller.add(1);
```

it will throw the error `Bad state: Cannot add event after closing`

And canceling a subscription means from now onward you don't want to listen to incoming events from the stream.

In your example, if you add an event to steam after 2 seconds. it will not listen.

```
Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 7), () {
  controller.add(1);
  controller.close();
});
```

what docs say:

```
/// Closes the stream.
///
/// No further events can be added to a closed stream.
///
/// The returned future is the same future provided by [done].
/// It is completed when the stream listeners is done sending events,
/// This happens either when the done event has been sent,
/// or when the subscriber on a single-subscription stream is canceled.
Future close();
```

Comment: Yes, but should I cancel subscriptions after stream is closed or not?

Comment: Yes you should cancel your subscription, whether you close your steam or not. It should not depended on closing of your stream.

Comment: Because there might be case when you are adding and closing your stream after cancellation of your subscription.

Comment: I definitely closed my stream. Should I still cancel subscription? 

Comment: If you are definate of closing stream before moving out of scope then you need not to cancel subscription.

Comment: But mostly we cancel subscription before moving out of scope to avoid memory leak.

Comment: But would they be kept open forever? Garbage collector would not deal with them?

Comment: Yes they will kept open forever, waiting for event.

Answer (score 1):

A straight forward answer:
If you close your stream, cancel subscriptions. Otherwise, listeners will keep listening to a stream that will never happen ;)